# when i enter my android into download mode, it restarts like after 5 seconds. is this normal?

Tags: oppo-coloros

Brand: Oppo A92
Model: CPH2059
I tried installing a **USB driver** and it didn't work.
I hope you can help me with this, thanks

Comment: fastboot is disabled because Oppo does not allow to unlock bootloader. therefore no driver to be installed